# OpenJPA PersistenceException: LongId cannot be cast to MyEntityClass... @OneToMany in combination with FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, annotations, one-to-many, fetch, openjpa

When I try to get an object from my database via entity manager that includes a further object that is annotated with @OneToMany and the parameter "fetch = FetchType.EAGER", I got the following exception (below are more Information about my entities and testcases):

```
[ERROR 15:50:40] projectNameRestController.catchEmAll(75) | general error occurred
<openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId cannot be cast to de.projectName.domain.test.Parent
FailedObject: select p from Parent p [java.lang.String]
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1027)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:926)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1033)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.java:2381)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationToManyInverseKeyFieldStrategy.loadElement(RelationToManyInverseKeyFieldStrategy.java:90)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationCollectionInverseKeyFieldStrategy.loadElement(RelationCollectionInverseKeyFieldStrategy.java:76)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.processEagerParallelResult(StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.java:313)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.loadEagerParallel(StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.java:247)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.loadEagerParallel(FieldMapping.java:916)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1059)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:636)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.load(DelegatingStoreManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.load(ROPStoreManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.loadFields(StateManagerImpl.java:3108)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.load(StateManagerImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:926)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1033)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:280)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.java:2381)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:274)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.InstanceResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(InstanceResultObjectProvider.java:60)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1251)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at de.projectName.dao.impl.AccountingDaoImpl.getDistributionsByProvider(AccountingDaoImpl.java:217)
    at de.projectName.dao.impl.AccountingDaoImpl.getDistributionsByProvider(AccountingDaoImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getDistributionsByProvider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getDistributionsByProvider(Unknown Source)
    at de.projectName.controller.rest.AccountingprojectNameRestController.getAllUnaccountedDistributions(AccountingprojectNameRestController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
    at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId cannot be cast to de.projectName.domain.test.Parent
    at de.projectName.domain.test.Child.pcReplaceField(Child.java)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.replaceField(StateManagerImpl.java:3213)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.storeObjectField(StateManagerImpl.java:2643)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.storeObject(StateManagerImpl.java:2633)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.setMappedBy(JDBCStoreManager.java:478)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:404)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:1046)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1004)
    ... 126 more
```

---

**I created 2 new entities for my tests, they look like this:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "parentGen")
@TableGenerator(name = "parentGen", table = "jpa_sequence", pkColumnName = "ID",
        pkColumnValue = "parent", valueColumnName = "SEQUENCE_VALUE", allocationSize = 1)
public long oid;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Child> children;


public long getOid() {
    return oid;
}

public void setOid(long oid) {
    this.oid = oid;
}

public List<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "childGen")
@TableGenerator(name = "childGen", table = "jpa_sequence", pkColumnName = "ID",
        pkColumnValue = "child", valueColumnName = "SEQUENCE_VALUE")
public long oid;

@ManyToOne
private Parent parent;


public long getOid() {
    return oid;
}

public void setOid(long oid) {
    this.oid = oid;
}

public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

---

Further information:

- My jpql: **select p from Parent p**
- If I change the FetchType to **"LAZY"** (or leave it just out) I got my
  result normaly and the children object (the list) is null of course,
  but if I call the getter of the list now (in the transaction), the object will be filled
  normaly **without** this exception.
- Furthermore this exception does **not** occur when I have just 1 parent
  with child objects. I can have several parents and children in my tables, but when
  more than 1 parent have children referenced in the database, this exception
  will be thrown.
- Also if I change the type of "oid" from "long" to "int" the exception will change, too: "...LongId cannot be cast... -> ...IntId cannot be cast..."
- I used: Java 8 with jpa 2.1.0 and 2.2.2, Java 6 with jpa 2.2.2
- MySQL Database
- Apache Tomcat

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I haven't scanned through your entire problem set yet but I can tell you `@TableGenerator` is not needed, JPA will do all that stuff for you. Edit* so remove `@TableGenerator` and change to this line `@GeneratedValue(strategey = GenerationType.IDENTITY`)

Comment: I wish I could buy you a beer! Oddly enough, I have been trying to create this bug that you've encountered all morning. Please open a JIRA and I'll start to look at it --  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA

Comment: I created an "Issue"
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2505